# Who was the oldest warrior to fight Mahabharata war?

Tags: mahabharata

**Was it King Bahlika , Bhagadatta or someone else?**

Please note that I am asking about oldest who actually fought in battlefield.

About [Bahlika](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahlika_(Mahabharata)), wiki says

> He was the elder brother of Shantanu
> And oldest to fight in war.

About [Bhagadatta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagadatta), wiki says

> Bhagadatta was arguably the oldest of all the warriors on the battlefield. At this time he was very old. He was so old, that he had to tie a silk cloth over his forehead so that the skin flap of his eyebrows would stay in place and would not fall down to obstruct his vision.

(For readers interested, Arjuna had to cut this silk napkin so that Bhagadatta get blinded by wrinkles and get killed who was otherwise undefeatable. )

Comment: So he gets “blinded by wrinkles and get killed” Pejorative, kinda ageist and disparaging to describe this guy like that. Eyebrow flap. Least he was out there doing his best and trying contribute.

Comment: @devibhakt it is just perspective. It is natural for him to had those wrinkles (every old person does) but he was still undefeated despite his age. That’s admirable. That’s how I understand

Comment: I didn’t mean you ! @ketan I meant the description from the original and wiki. And I was half joking :) Sometimes the descriptions in religious texts, it’s like, wait did they really say that ? Lotsa snark & sarcasm :D